# Push event not received in originating browser

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-push

I have a primefaces datagrid that I'm trying to update using primefaces Push. I can see that the onMessage method is called, however the component itself only updates if I have set a breakpoint in the onMessage method. This is the handler:

```
@PushEndpoint("/prices")
public class PricesResource {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("PricesResource");

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public OrderBook onMessage(OrderBook orderBook) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "PricesResource.onMessage price {0}", orderBook.getPrice());
        return orderBook;
    }
}
```

This is the code I call to update the component in my index.xhtml:

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/prices" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(data) 
        {
            updateWidgets();
        } 
    </script>

    <p:remoteCommand name="updateWidgets"
             actionListener="#{parliamentManager.findLatestPrices}"
             update="resultDisplay"/>
```

And the component is just at the bottom of index.xhtml at the moment:

```
<h:panelGroup id="resultDisplay">                          
<p:dataGrid id="prices" var="orderBooks" value="#{parliamentManager.latestPricesResults}" columns="3" rows="12">
<p:column>
    <p:panel header="#{orderBooks.bidOrderId.member.memberId}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:outputText value="#{orderBooks.price}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
</p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I'm pretty stumped as to why that is, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you 'debugged' al network traffic using the browser developer tools? Checked correctness of values of 'update' attributes etc?

Comment: @Kukeltje I'll give it a go but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is the remote command executed, what does its response look like (isit e.g. updated but with the same data), any errors in the response, is the method called etc…

Comment: @Kukeltje The remote command is executed, yes. I'm not sure if it's updated with the same data yet. One interesting thing that I noted is that if I open two browsers and update my list (i.e. change latestPriceResults) it will consistently update the component in the other browser window but won't update it's own component. I'm not sure what that indicates.

Comment: I've added logging to my javascript handlers and I can see the handler is being fired and with the correct data (although I don't use the object returned to the handler) in the receiving browser. I can also see that the handler is not fired in the browser that submits the form, (assuming we're using two browsers) So that's still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Then your push event is send to the wrong or just one browser. Debug the push more…  is it connected? Add tge different methods for connect, disconnect etc in the endpoint, see what happens…  again all basic debug stuff

Comment: And your title should effectively be "push event not received in 'originating' browser"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to add the autoRun attribute to my remoteCommand tag, this updates the component after the form has been submitted and the page reloads.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateWidgets"
    actionListener="#{parliamentManager.findLatestPrices}"
    update="resultDisplay"
    autoRun="true"/>
```

Comment: Weird solution. Then you must havea different problem somewhere or code that is relevant which youdid not post!